# Basic JS operators for condition

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Let's say I have this code:

```
if (x1 >= 300 && y1 >= 10) { ... }
```

I want to say, if x1 is greater than or equal to 300 AND is smaller than or equal to 800, as well as if y1 is greater than or equal to 10 AND is smaller than or equal to 30. How can I write that?

Comment: Did you not try something simple like: `(x1 >= 300 && x1 <= 600) && (y1 >= 10 && y1 <= 30)` ?

Comment: I think you know the answer to that question.

Comment: I asked your same question when I was first learning how to program too. I thought there might be a between operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
if ((x1 >= 300 && x1 <= 800) && (y1 >= 10 && y1 <= 30)) {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ( (300 =< x1 && x1 =< 800) && (10 =< y1 && y1 =< 30) ) { ... }
```

Comment: That's great too. Thank you /salute.

Answer (score -2):

```
if((x1 >= 300 && x1 <= 800) && (y1 >= 10 && y1 <= 30))
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```

You could write a between function yourself

```
function between(x, min, max) {
  return x >= min && x <= max;
}
// ...
if (between(x, 300, 800)) {
   // something
 }
```

Comment: probably because your `if` syntax is invalid

Comment: @charlietfl thanks man. I didn't noticed that. Corrected that now